# Unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Here is my code where testResponseType and testRequestType are auto generated classes. And the error is unable to marshal testRequestType as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation for auto generated classes.

```
    fun test(
        var1: testType?,
        var2: testType?
    ): testResponseType {
        val request = testRequestType()
        request.var1 = var1
        request.var2 = var2
        return webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request) as testResponseType 
    }
```

Is there any way to solve this problem or I need to change something in xsd or wsdl file in order to add @XmlRootElement to the testRequestType class?